# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make post call using XMLHTTPRequest, and is getting following message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://some-link' from origin
>   'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.

There are similar threads that says to either add CORS header, in which I have done already.

What I'm curious is that this exact same codes, when turned into AJAX works fine (without having to have others go through CORS configuration).
Since AJAX simply is a framework built out of JavaScript, why does this message show up when coding without AJAX, and purely out of JavaScript?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('POST', url, true)
xhr.send(data)
```

vs.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    data: data
});
```

Latter works fine. What additional/hidden implementation is there within ajax?

Answer (score -1):

Open DOM Inspector, click on the request and find the difference between those two requests. There will be a difference.

That "null" origin is probably because you use IFRAME with attribute sandbox, right? To solve this you need to make sure that

- Requested resource (in network panel) returns "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" among RESPONSE headers (you said you've done that)
- Keep in mind that preflight checks use OPTIONS requests (neither GET nor POST) so make sure that your server sends aforementioned header when the resources is requested using OPTIONS request. You should see some error message about OPTIONS request in console right before CORS error if that is the case. (For example NGINX repsonds with error 405 to OPTIONS requests by default.)

You can check that using command line curl like that
`curl 'https://www.example.com/my-url-that-fails-here/' -X OPTIONS -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' -H 'Origin: null' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with' --compressed -D - -O /dev/null`
This should mimic the real browser quite closely.